# How can I rewrite a commonJS statement into an ECMAScript import when it uses consecutive requires on one line?

Tags: javascript, commonjs

I am new to JavaScript for the most part and looking to convert this line into an import statement.

var sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));

I've already converted the other requires into imports but couldn't find an example of this syntax.

Comment: Refer to the readme from gulp-sass: https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass?tab=readme-ov-file#importing-it-into-your-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's just a nested require

```
var sass = require('gulp-sass')(
    require('sass')
);
```

should convert to something like

```
import sass from 'sass'
import gulpSass from 'gulp-sass'

var gulpSassInstance = gulpSass(sass)
```